# open a text file that has been created

Tags: python, python-3.x

In This Password Manager Program , I'Ve Created A Function Named Add(). This Will Actually Append The Username And Password In The File . Now How Do I Open The Same File in function view() That Has Been Created Using The Add() Function. Here Is The Code .

```
def add():
    username = input('enter your username : ')
    password = input('enter your password : ')
    with open('passwords.txt','a') as f :
        f.write('username : '+ username +' , '+ 'passwor : '+ password + '\n' )

def view():
    with open('passwords.txt','r') as l :
        l.read()

while True :

    mode = input('do you want to view the password or add a new password ? ')
    if mode == 'view':
        view()
    elif mode == 'add':
        add()

    else:
        continue
```

Comment: now can you check ?

Comment: In `view()` you read from the file, but don't do anything with what you read.  Did you want to return the results so that you might `print()` them in your loop, or `print()` them right from `view()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
def view():
    with open('passwords.txt','r') as l :
        data = l.read()
    print(data)
```

You already got most of the code in place. Read the data to a variable and print it.

Accept the answer if it helps.